# how to change magento backend to different ip address

Tags: magento-1.9, custom-admin-url

friends I am struggling with how to change Magento 1 backend to a different IP(other than storefront) address.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

go to Admin>>System>>Configuration>>Advanced>>Admin.

```
Click on Admin Base Url.
```

Click drop down in front of Use Custom Admin Url to "Yes" and Add your custom admin Url.

If you want to add the Custom Admin path you can manage by enabling the Use Custom Admin path.

Comment: all(admin) js and css are 404 after this

Comment: You need to manage the js and Css Path for Default config Scope. Note: It will be different than your website configuration.

Comment: how can we do that can you explain

Comment: Go to Admin>>System>>configuration>>General>>Web and manage the CSS and Js path for Default Config scope. and for Website level configuration you can manage the separate path by Un-selecting the Use default checkbox

Comment: ok thanks but can we do it in db way because i can't access admin panel properly without css and js

Comment: You can use this (Replace adminstoreurl.com with your actual Url,                                                                                           INSERT INTO `core_config_data` (`scope`, `scope_id`, `path`, `value`) VALUES
('default', 0, 'web/unsecure/base_skin_url', 'http://adminstoreurl.com/skin/'),
('default', 0, 'web/secure/base_skin_url', 'https://adminstoreurl.com/skin/');